# How to backup user generated data stored in Core Data to server?

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

My application will gather information from customers and backup them to server. Every time users insert, update, or delete their information, the app will try to backup latest data to server. If there are connection errors or other problems, the app will try to backup all not updated data during the next opportunity.

My question is that is there any nice solution to accomplish it? My current solution is: 
The managed object has a attribute called `is_updated` with default value: false.

1. When user insert data, the app reads the row attributes and objectID and send them to server as JSON. If the server successfully insert the data into mysql, it respond with the objectID. The HTTP handler set the `is_updated` of the row of the objectID to true.
2. Updating is handled like insertion. To find the record to update, I have to add a objectID field to the server table.
3. To handle deletion, I need another attribute `is_deleted`. When user deletes a record, the app will hide the record by setting `is_deleted` to true. After the server delete the record, the app finally delete the record.
4. During any of the three operations, the app will check are there any un-updated records and process them together.

But I feel the solution is somehow ugly. It's really complex to handle multiple insertion, deletion operations mixed together. Maybe I have to send multiple HTTP requests in a operation queue.If the user re-install the app, the app needs to fetch all the records from the server and store locally. But their objectIDs don't work any more.

Do you have some better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not so bad. The queuing of the HTTP requests is really a standard thing to do, so that should not be a big problem.

Just do *not* use the objectIDs on your server. They are really unique to the database on one particular device. Their main purpose is to identify managed objects across different managed object contexts. Instead us your own id, maybe a server generated one that is authoritative.

The obvious "elegant" alternative is to use Apple's integration of iCloud with Core Data. Then you have to do absolutely nothing on the server side. The drawback is that you cannot access the user info (which might be desired). The much more significant drawback (showstopper) is that it does not work reliably (see my SOF question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478517/more-icloud-core-data-synching-woes)).