# If I use a Core Data manual migration, can I later integrate iCloud sync?

Tags: core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

I want to run a Core Data migration that applies a value transformation on a property, specifically mapping one string value to another, which I don't believe can be handled by a lightweight migration.

Eventually (but not in the next release of my app), I want to add iCloud sync. I read that [iCloud sync requires you to only use light-weight migrations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/vmCloud/vmCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH9-SW1). Can I use a non-lightweight migration now and then integrate iCloud sync later, and will doing so make things harder for me later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement iCloud later, i.e. after the non-lightweight migration. No, things should not be harder for you later. You can assume iCloud does not store your versioned models to construct the final managed object model, but just takes the final one. It is the migration itself that iCloud would not support.

That being said, I have had [dismal experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14478517/427083) with iCloud and Core Data. Don't say you have not been warned.